# I want to edit my labels while using builder: Bulma::FormBuilder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have used bulma form builder in my formFor in rails slim views,

By default when i set some text field it will automatically assign that text field but i want o edit that text field keeping that bulma form style,

Here is what i have used:

```
 = form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name),builder: Bulma::FormBuilder) do |f|
            .field
              .control
                = f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Enter Username", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'username', class: 'input'
            br
            .field
              .control
                = f.email_field :email, placeholder: "Enter E-Mail", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'email', class: 'input'
            br
            .field
              .control
                = f.password_field :password, placeholder: "Enter Password", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'password', class: 'input'
            br
            .field
              .control
                = f.password_field :confirm_password, placeholder: "Confirm Password", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'confirm_password', class: 'input'
            br
            .control-group
```

By doing this i dont assign any label bulma assign it automatically but i want to edit those labels like i want username to be labeled as , "Your Username" Etc..

Comment: Anybody can guide me on this?

Comment: have you tried
`f.text_field :username, placeholder: "Enter Username", autofocus: true, autocomplete: 'username', class: 'input', label: "My Custom Label"`

Comment: @dbugger It worked You Saved my Day Thank You!

Comment: @dbugger can i add text styles like bold italic and under line or colors to that label?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯, likely would have to do via css

Comment: label: "anything" is not working with f.select fields? why?

Comment: @dbugger where do i add label here?                                                                             = f.select(:donor_status, options_for_select([['Parent', 'Parent'], ['Sperm Donor', 'Sperm Donor'],['Egg Donor', 'Egg Donor'],['Donor Ofspring', 'Donor Ofspring'],['Other', 'Other']]),{prompt: "Please Select"}, { include_blank: true })

Comment: Please add an answer and mark as accepted (@dbugger , @usman).